# Drag an object with touch and flick to throw it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I'm trying to allow users to drag objects across the screen with touch and lift their finger to have the objects "fly away" in the direction they were being moved.

This is what I was trying.

```
    Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3 (touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y, transform.position.z);
    velocity = newPosition - transform.position;

    // User is dragging the object around
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, newPosition, Time.deltaTime * 25f);
    }

    // User lifts finger
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)){
            transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(velocity, ForceMode2D.Force); // Also tried with transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = velocity; and transform.position += velocity; // The later works but doesn't allow for physics later on
        }
```

With this approach the object seems to have low frame rate when dragged. Also when swiping/flicking the object not always keeps the right direction and it flies very slowly (I probably have to multiply it by a factor related to the updates per second but I'm not sure).

Any idea how to make this work smoothly?

EDIT

I corrected the direction when flicking the object by using an average of the object's velocity for the last few frames, however I still can't get the speed right. It still has a low frame rate when dragged around (could this could be corrected by using a physics approach instead of directly writing to the position?)

Comment: I added an official source to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the velocity while you drag the object and keep applying it after the you release it.

```
Vector3 velocity;
..
void Update() {  
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
        Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        velocity = new Vector3 (touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y, transform.position.z) - transform.position;
    }
    transform.position += velocity;
}
```

Edit:

If you want your object to be affected only by the touch position while being dragged you can set `isKinematic = true` on the rigidbody and set its position
directly. Otherwise you can update the velocity so the object moves towards the touch position. 
  Finaly on MouseButtonUp set the velocity to the average velocity of the last  frames (up to a max of 10 if the drag lasts for more than 10 frames).

```
..        
    private PositionQueue pastPositions; 
    void Awake(){
        pastPositions = new PositionQueue(10);
    }

    void Update(){
        Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3 (touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y, transform.position.z);

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            //transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic=true;  
            pastPositions.Clear();
        }
        // User is dragging the object around
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {   
            pastPositions.Enqueue(newPosition);
            //transform.position = newPosition;                      
            //transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, newPosition, Time.deltaTime * 25f);
            transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = (newPosition - transform.position) * 10;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)){
            //transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;   
            velocity = (newPosition - pastPositions.Peek()) / pastPositions.Count;
            transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = velocity * 20; // Also tried with transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = velocity; and transform.position += velocity; // The later works but doesn't allow for physics later on
        }
    }
}

class PositionQueue{
    private Queue<Vector3> _queue;
    private int _maxSize;
    public int Count {
        get {
            return _queue.Count;
        }
    }
    public PositionQueue(int maxSize){
        _maxSize = maxSize;
        _queue = new Queue<Vector3>();
    }
    public void Enqueue(Vector3 v){
        if(_queue.Count>=_maxSize){
            _queue.Dequeue();
        }
        _queue.Enqueue(v);
    }
    public Vector3 Peek(){
        return _queue.Peek();
    }
    public void Clear(){
        _queue.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @plutoo this seems close to what I want to do. My main problem is that changing the position does't change the velocity, which causes trouble afterwards to know where to object is moving and apply forces to it. I tried transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity  = velocity; inside Input.GetMouseButton(0) however it seems it moves slower than it really should. Do I need to multiply velocity with some particular variable?

Comment: `transform.position =new Vector3 (touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y, transform.position.z);` inside `if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))` should keep the object at the mouse position. After you can  add some force or modify the velocity in with the information from `velocity` `if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)){ `. The idea is while you drag the object calculate the direction of movement and the intensity (posibly over a number of frames) and when you release you apply the force.

Comment: hi @Pluto, this is close to what I want. I have managed to get an average of the velocity of the object for the last few frames to make it more reliable. My problem is that I don't like changing the position directly, how can I apply a force to the object or write to the velocity instead?

Comment: I edited the answer. I am not sure tho if you want to teleport the object to the touch position or move towards it while you drag.

Comment: Hi @Pluto I couldn't understand why the velocity is multiplied by 20. In my tests the best way to maintain the object's speed was to multiply it by 30. I think it's because that's the frame rate. Could that be wrong?

Comment: `transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = 1*Vector3.right;` is like saying `void FixedUpdate(){ transform.position += 1 * Time.fixedDeltaTime * Vector3.right;`. `Time.fixedDeltaTime` is ~ .02 (the default phisics timestep). So Rigidbody2D.velocity = (currentPosition - previousPosition) * (1/Time.fixedDeltaTime) . 1/Time.fixedDeltaTime ~ 50.

Comment: When I use the PositionQueue class it says 'Queue' does not contain a definition for 'Dequeue'..?

Answer (score 1):

You can use information from Input.GetTouch(i) to move an object around based on finger movement and then apply a velocity.

**Move and flick scene object based on finger movement**

```
[SerializeField] float speedMultiplier = 1f;

void Update() {

    for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) {

        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {

            transform.position = touch.position;

        } else if (touch.phase = TouchPhase.Ended) {

            velocity = touch.deltaPosition.magnitude / touch.deltaTime * speedMultiplier;

        }

    }    

}
```

Source: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html

Answer (score 0):

if you mean "release" by "destroying" it, use

```
gameObject.SetActive(false); //Or 
Destroy(gameObject);
```

If you wish to maintain the speed it is currently moving:

```
rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(x,y,z); //or alternatively:
rigidbody.AddRelativeForce (new Vector(x,y,z));
```

Comment: hi @David by release I meant lifting the finger. What I want to do is have it maintain the speed it was moving when you lift the finger. The problem is that since I was changing the position directly the object does't really has an speed so I'm not sure how to do it.